# How long before packages with bug fixes appear in repository?

Tags: bug-reporting

I am using Ubuntu 18.10.

There is a bug reported in the duplicity package [Duplicity fails with UnicodeDecodeError in uexc function](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/duplicity/+bug/1770929)

According to the report linked to above the bug was fixed in the package `duplicity - 0.7.18.2-1ubuntu3.1`. Yet in Synaptic the Duplicity package is still at version `duplicity - 0.7.17-0ubuntu2`.

How long does it generally take for a bug fix release to appear in the repos?